# Geo-spatial data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, storage, analytics, geospatial

How to store Geo-spatial data in Mongodb?
How MongoDB supports or stores Geo-spatial data compared to normal data?
How to command/suggest Mongodb to consider the inputted data(JSON Object) as Geo-spatial data?
What are the various features/support provided by MongoDB for Geo-Spatial data?

Please help me with good documentation/Reference link as I am new to MongoDb and the concepts of Geo-spatial data.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the MongoDB docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

And continue with my webinar:
https://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/getting-started-with-geospatial-data-in-mongodb

MongoDB treats geo data like other data since the Document model permits arbitrarily complex shapes.   In general, a geo field is a substructure with a `type`fields and a `coordinates`field, e.g.

```
{
  name: "Buzz",
  location: { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ array of rings, each ring is an array of points, and a point is small array of [lon,lat] ]}
```

}

Disclosure:  I used to work at MongoDB.

Comment: Thank u buzz. When i googled the topic i got the link that u have included, but it does not explain well to beginners hence i stacked the question(s).... also thanks for the slides i will go through it.

Comment: Hai buzz awesome slides helped me a lot!!... can you please answer this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917361/why-are-coordinates-of-polygon-geojson-objects-stored-in-an-array-of-array